# How to append to a file being used by "dotnet"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, process

When I started catching and displaying my logging exceptions on my console application, I realized that quite a number of my log messages are absent due to the following error

> The process cannot access the file '[MY_LOG_FILE_PATH]' because it is
>   being used by another process

This is how I log my messages on a log file (I create a new file which every run of the application). The variables `callingClass` and `callingMethod` are respectively the class and the method which are calling the Log function.

```
try
{
    var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
    string callingMethod = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
    string callingClass = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().ReflectedType.Name;
    string logText = string.Format(format, DateTime.Now, "INFO", callingClass, callingMethod, message);
    if (!Directory.Exists("log"))
        Directory.CreateDirectory("log");
    if (!File.Exists(logFilePath))
        File.Create(logFilePath);
    using (FileStream f = new FileStream(logFilePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(f))
        sw.WriteLine(logText);
}
catch(IOException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Processes locking the file:");
    var lockingProcesses = FileHelper.WhoIsLocking(logFilePath);
    foreach (Process p in lockingProcesses)
        Console.WriteLine("Process: " + p.ProcessName + "   Machine:" + p.MachineName);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    Console.WriteLine("The following log could not be written to file: " + message);
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    Console.ResetColor();
}
```

When I caught the `IOException` causing the above situation that, I found out that the process that possesses the log file is **"dotnet"** residing on machine **"."**, which I assume is the current machine.

How do I not lose my log messages?

**IDE**: Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.0.4

**.NET Framework Version**: 4.7.03190

**OS**: Windows 10 Pro 64x

Comment: Whats the context of that code, for example are you calling it from multiple threads?

Comment: One problem with your code is that `File.Create` creates the file and also opens it.  So in the next line when you try to create a new `FileStream` the file is already opened and throws an error.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Genius! You were right and I seriously could not even remotely guess that the file should be closed after creation. Please post this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.Create` creates the file and also opens it. So in the next line when you try to create a new `FileStream` the file is already opened and throws an error.

One option is to immediately call `Close` on the file stream when creating it:

```
File.Create(logFilePath).Close();
```

Another is to just use `StreamWriter` to open/create the file and skip using the `FileStream` altogether.  Passing `true` means to append to the file if it exists.

```
try
{
    var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
    string callingMethod = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
    string callingClass = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().ReflectedType.Name;
    string logText = string.Format(format, DateTime.Now, "INFO", callingClass, callingMethod, message);

    if (!Directory.Exists("log"))
        Directory.CreateDirectory("log");

    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(logFilePath, true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(logText);
    } 
}
catch(IOException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Processes locking the file:");
    var lockingProcesses = FileHelper.WhoIsLocking(logFilePath);
    foreach (Process p in lockingProcesses)
        Console.WriteLine("Process: " + p.ProcessName + "   Machine:" + p.MachineName);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    Console.WriteLine("The following log could not be written to file: " + message);
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    Console.ResetColor();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pushing your messages into a shared BlockingCollection, and have a thread which reads from this and writes to your log file.

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example using the code above? / Also how does the `BlockingCollection` work in case the program crashes?

Comment: Do you have the files opened somewhere else? Are you running VS as an ADMIN? Do you have any permission restrictions on the folder?

Comment: @Zinov Yes, I have Admin rights and the folder is not shared with anyone else. I also tried moving the folder containing the log file to the desktop. Mind that, this does not happen all the time. Some log messages make their way to the file.